# Rows of a table in IEEE format?

Tags: tables, ieeetran, wrap

I am trying to insert a table in IEEE transaction template and I want the row borders of the table of varying thickness as shown in the following figure. Can you please help me with that ? Also, even after trying for hours, can't get the text wrapped up.
[image]

Please Note:I have to use the IEEE template, can't change that. Which follows that this table needs to be in 1 column (out of 2)of a page. My code is given below:

```
\documentclass[journal]{IEEEtran}

\begin{document}

\setlength{\arrayrulewidth}{0.5mm}
\setlength{\tabcolsep}{18pt}
\renewcommand{\arraystretch}{1.5}
\begin{tabular}{ |p{0.9cm}|p{0.9cm}|p{0.9cm}|p{0.9cm}|  }
\hline
\multicolumn{4}{|c|}{Title} \\
\hline
Serial Number& Column1&Column2&Column3\\
\hline
Row 1& AF & AFG  & AFG  \\
%\specialrule{0.01em}{0.1em}{0.1em}
\hline
Row 2& AX   & ALA & AFG \\
Row 3&AL & ALB  & AFG \\
Row 4&DZ & DZA  & AFG \\
Row 5& AS & ASM  & AFG  \\
Row 6& AD & AND   & AFG  \\
Row 6& AOffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffff& AGO & AFG  \\
%\specialrule{0.01em}{0.1em}{0.1em}
\hline
\end{tabular}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE. Were you surprised that LaTeX has no idea how to hyphenate `AOffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffff`? How, in your opinion, should this non-word be hyphenated?

Answer (score 3):

Since you must follow the style guidelines provided by the `IEEEtran` document class, I wouldn't mess with the values of `\tabcolsep` and `\arrayrulewidth`. I would also embed the tabular material in a `table` environment. To line-break long non-words such as `AOffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffff`, I suggest encasing them in a `\seqsplit` macro. About the line styles for horizontal lines: Is inserting vertical whitespace instead of drawing a broken line an option?

Do consider improving the appearance of the table by (a) getting rid of all vertical lines (the IEEEtran style guidelines do *not* require the use of vertical rules), (b) assuring adequate column widths, and (c) using the line-drawing macros of the [booktabs](https://ctan.org/pkg/booktabs/) package instead of `\hline` and `\cline`.

[image]

```
\documentclass[journal]{IEEEtran}
\usepackage{booktabs} % for well-spaced horizontal rules
\usepackage{calc}     % for \widthof macro
\usepackage{seqsplit} % for \seqsplit macro

\begin{document}

\begin{table}[h]
\centering
\renewcommand{\arraystretch}{1.05} % 1.5 is much too large
\caption{Title}

\begin{tabular}{@{} p{\widthof{Number}} *{3}{p{\widthof{Column1}}} @{}} 
\toprule
Serial Number & Column1 &Column2 & Column3 \\
\midrule
Row 1& AF & AFG  & AFG  \\
\addlinespace % whitespace is a very effective visual separator
Row 2& AX & ALA  & AFG  \\
Row 3& AL & ALB  & AFG  \\
Row 4& DZ & DZA  & AFG  \\
Row 5& \seqsplit{AOffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffff} & ASM  & AFG  \\
Row 6& Hello World & AND  & AFG  \\
Row 7& AO & AGO  & AFG  \\
\bottomrule
\end{tabular}
\end{table}

\hrule % illustrate column width

\end{document}
```

Comment: thanks for the answer. That actually solves wrapping issue. But even if I were to let go of row borders, the column borders are not visible here too.That may work with numbers but my table has got text in it and the table looks messy in this way.

Comment: @CuriousCosmopolitan - The "looks messy" issue is independent of the presence or absence of vertical rules. The `p` column type fully justifies its contents; this isn't a good idea if the columns are quite narrow. I suggest you (a) load the `array` and `ragged2e` packages and (b) change `p{\widthof{Number}}` to `>{\RaggedRight}p{\widthof{Number}}` and `p{\widthof{Column1}` to `>{\RaggedRight}p{\widthof{Column1}`, respectively. That way, the cell contents are typeset ragged-right while also permitting hyphenation. This should make for a much less messy appearance.